# Kentico Media Library not syncing with MVC project

Tags: model-view-controller, kentico, media-library

I'm using Kentico 9 with MVC. When I add a image to the media library it is not copied to the MVC application. I am using the default media library location which resolves to  `~/site/media` but the image is only accessible from the admin domain. `admin.site.com/site/media/image.jpg` and not from `site.com/site/media/image.jpg`.

For the image to be accessible, I have to manually copy the images to the corresponding folder.

My admin and MVC site are hosted on the same server using two different IIS app pools. However, we plan to separate these in the near future, so its important that this synchronization works correctly.

1. Under Web Farms, I have only one active server.
2. Both web.config files have the same `CMSHashStringSalt` values.

based on [the Documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc/developing-mvc-applications/retrieving-content-on-mvc-sites/working-with-media-libraries-on-mvc-sites): 
`By default, content of media libraries is synchronized via web farms and duplicated between Kentico and your MVC application.`

EDIT:
 What is the best practice for configuring media libraries with MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was simply adding `<add key="CMSWebFarmServerName" value="MVCApplication"/>` to the MVC application

[SOURCE](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc/starting-with-mvc-development):TLDR

`If you plan to run the Kentico and MVC applications on the same domain (for example, distinguished by port numbers and run in different virtual folders), you need to manually assign unique server names to the web farm servers. To set a web farm server name, see Step 5 in Configuring web farms manually.`

Since these sites are hosted on the same machine, i needed to specify a unique server name.

Comment: I have the `<add key="CMSWebFarmServerName" value="MVCApplication"/>` app setting in web.config but still having this issue. Maybe need to add `<add key="CMSWebFarmSynchronizeMediaFiles" value="true"/>`? https://docs.kentico.com/k12/configuring-kentico/configuring-the-environment-for-content-editors/configuring-media-libraries

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the [MVC setup](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc/starting-with-mvc-development#StartingwithMVCdevelopment-SettinguptheKenticoinstance) is that you should either have two servers setup manually in your web farm or have the web farm set to auto.  As you only have one, there is nothing to synchronize. That you only have one server in your server list makes me think that the synchronization is not going to work.  If your web farm is set to auto, perhaps try to [configure it manually](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/configuring-kentico/optimizing-website-performance/setting-up-web-farms/configuring-web-farm-servers#Configuringwebfarmservers-Configuringwebfarmsmanually).

Comment: You maybe correct, I've manually configured my Webfarm and still no luck. I think the web farm section is only looking for "Admin servers" and does not consider the MVC project a separate server

Comment: Yeah, looking at this article it suggests you may need your own controller here or want to look into external storage.  https://docs.kentico.com/k10/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc/developing-mvc-applications/retrieving-content-on-mvc-sites/working-with-media-libraries-on-mvc-sites

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Admin and MVC running as two site under IIS pointing to the same database? Also, do you have the license key with 2 servers modifier? (you will need to request that from your sales rep)

Comment: Yes, both sites are pointing to the same DB and content is flowing correctly,
 including attachments (except Media Libraries). Yes, i have 2 licenses. 

2 for the admin domain and 2 for the site domain

Comment: content and attachments are in DB so no problem. Does the account used to run each application pool has the modify permission to /site/media folder, especially the MVC site. Also, check the web farm app > tasks, do you see any tasks about media library stock in there? Try upload an image from admin site media library, then monitor the web farm task, also look into even log app to see if some permission error comes up.

Comment: Yes, the folder has all the proper permissions. Also, No, I do not see any task when there is only one server in the web farm section. If I add a server manually the task start to accumulate.

Comment: I mean enable Auto web farm, so the server identifies both sites. Don't add it manually. Is the MVC site URL added to the Sites application?